# A simple probability model for an epidemic simulation

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I'm creating a epidemic simulation program in Python, but I'm stuck trying to determine the probability of being infected (if exposed).

I have an m x n grid with 0's and '1 (0's represent healty cells, 1's represent infected cells). For simplicity i'll use a 3x3 grid for this example.

```
 0  1  1
 0  0  0
 0  1  0
```

The center value at coords (1, 1) will take the sum of its neighbours (sum = 3). This means that this particular cell is exposed to a virus from three different infected cells.

Let's say that the probability of catching the virus is 0.25 (assuming 0.0 immunity) for every exposure (they are independent of each other). I have a different grid with the immunity values (ranging from 0 to 1 where 1 is immune).

I cannot for the love of Jesus figure out how to set up the math to determine the probability of the cell being infected.

Please help :)

Comment: How to setup what math? You did not specify any equations.

Comment: A SIR model is probably what you want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology

Answer (score 0):

You can create a kernel `k` and convolve on the grid `a`. This gives you count of infected neighbors for each cell. Then you can calculate as shown below. I am not an epidemiology expert. I have used simple logic to solve this.

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.ndimage import convolve

infection_prob = 0.25
# immunity = np.random.standard_normal(9)
a = np.array([[0,1,0], [1,0,0], [0,0,1]])
# immunity = immunity.reshape(a.shape)
k = np.ones(a.shape)
x,y = 1,1 
k[x,y] = 0

c = convolve(a, k, mode="constant")
print((1-infection_prob)**c[x,y])
>> 0.421875
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I formulated my question alittle bit inprecise. I was wondering about how to calculate the probability, not how to check a cell's neighbours :)

Answer (score 0):

If probability of infection occurring from a single exposure event is $0.25$ then probability of an infection occurring from three independent events is $1-(1-0.25)^3= 1 - 0.75^3 = 0.578125.$

Comment: What about atleast one?

Comment: That was the probability of at least one exposure resulting in infection, since the cell either get's infected or it doesn't from any single exposure.